# Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException: invalid attribute: :css

Tags: css, css-selectors, watir, watir-webdriver

I am pretty sure watir-webdriver had css selector support, but looks like it is not there any more:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

$ gem -v
1.8.15

$ gem list selenium-webdriver
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
selenium-webdriver (2.17.0)

$ gem list watir-webdriver
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
watir-webdriver (0.4.1)

$ irb
> require "watir-webdriver"
 => true 

> browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x787eb29124fb7658 url="about:blank" title=""> 

> browser.goto "google.com"
 => "http://www.google.com.mx/" 

> browser.a(:css => "a").flash
Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException: invalid attribute: :css
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:228:in `assert_valid_as_attribute'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:209:in `normalize_selector'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:191:in `block in normalized_selector'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:188:in `each'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:188:in `normalized_selector'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:76:in `find_first_by_multiple'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:33:in `locate'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:285:in `locate'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:259:in `assert_exists'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:206:in `style'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.4.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:103:in `flash'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Environment: Mac OS X 10.7.2, Firefox 9.0.1.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

watir-webdriver currently only supports this if you use Browser#element

```
 browser.element(:css => "a")
```

We could add support for other element methods, but we'd have to find a way to handle e.g.

```
 browser.a(:css => "div.foo")
```

Comment: Thanks. For a moment I thought I was crazy. I remember it was working. I guess I was using `browser.element` then.

Answer (score 3):

Funny, enough I can still bypass a lot of limitations or missing functionality not exposed by watir making direct JS calls, e.g.

```
browser.execute_script('jQuery(\'div#td%s div a\').trigger(\'click\')' % reagent_id)
```

As I said, in some cases this the only way for me. It would be really cool to have a tighter integration into the DOM.

Comment: I think main difficulties in watir are caused by the fact that JavaScript is an asynchronous language.