# element not supported by watir webdriver

Tags: xpath, automation, watir-webdriver

So element_by_xpath has been removed from watir webdriver and I am wondering if there is something similar to this still in existence. Basically there is a path element (pie chart) that is clickable and I need to have a regression test set up to for it. The people who designed the website apparently thought it would be cool to have everything inside this thing to be custom tags and there is nothing supported by watir webdriver that I can point to, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: Can you include the HTML? Watir-webdriver supports custom tags, so it should be possible to help you design a good element definition--but only if we can see the HTML that we have to work with.

Comment: <path d="M 84.90791682189902 166.3745188594486 A 90.75 90.75 0 0 1 16…98642 30.250006900843204 L 163.5 121 A 0 0 0 0 0 163.5 121 Z" fill="rgb(192,192,192)" isTracker="1393886735245" fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" zIndex="1" style="cursor:pointer;"></path>

Comment: The problem is there are several that look like this and I have to distinguish them as well.

Comment: Assuming you don't like Justin's answer below, see his excellent answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722128/1904740 (Meanwhile, you must work with developers who hate you, given these HTML elements! Agony!)

Comment: Actually that link was awesome. It at least allowed me to interact with the tag but since I can't specify which <path> I want to interact with then I cant click on the one that will open the popup. These are svg widgets. I must continue to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`element_by_xpath` was replaced with an :xpath locator, which is used like any other locator such as :text.

For example, say you have a custom 'asdf' element in your html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <asdf>text</asdf>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you could locate the element via xpath like:

```
browser.element(:xpath => '//asdf').text
#=> "text"
```

The usual suggestion is to avoid xpath. If you are only using the xpath because of the tag name, you can use the :tag_name locator instead:

```
browser.element(:tag_name => 'asdf').text
#=> "text"
```